# RichTextBox doesnt show scrollbars and text goes off limit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a TabControl with one TabPage with a RichTextBox inside that I added with the windows form design tool and an option in a menu to add more TabPages and RichTextBoxes. When I fill the Richtextbox that I added manually with text the vertical scrollbar appears and the text is inside the limits od the textbox, but when I fill with text a richtextbox that I added with the menu option the text goes beyond the limits of the textbox and no scrollbars appear.

How can I make the richtextboxes that I add behave properly?

this is the code I use to add the tabpages and the richtetxboxes:

I've already tried setting multiline True and forcing the scrollbars.

EDIT: I know what it is. For some reason when I set the size of myRichTextBox it actually makes it bigger than the richtextbox I added in the design tool even tho they are the same size, so the text actually "fits" but it is off limits.

```
private void AgregarPestañaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = "Pestaña " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    string name = "richTextBox" + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
    RichTextBox myRichTextBox= new RichTextBox();
    myRichTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    myRichTextBox.Name = name;
    myRichTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
    myRichTextBox.TabIndex = 0;
    myRichTextBox.Text = "";
    myRichTextBox.Multiline = true;
    myRichTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedBoth ;
    textAreas.Add(myRichTextBox);
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(myRichTextBox);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}
```

This is the code inside `InitializeComponent()`:

```
// richTextBox1
// 
this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(480, 480);
this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
```

## UPDATE

I fixed the problem, apparently Visual Studio was scaled 125% and because of the way it detects the size of components, the values were incorrect.

Comment: It's time to take a look at `InitializeComponent` in `designer.cs` file of your form to figure out what properties has been set for the richtextbox which is working well.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yeah I have literally the same properties that are on `InitializeComponent`

Comment: I think it has something to do with the RichTextBox not updating when the text is introduced.

Comment: The code does't reproduce the problem or your problem description is not clear and accurate enough. I tried the code and it works as expected.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Okay, I know what it is. For some reason when I set the size of `myRichTextBox` it actually makes it bigger than the richtextbox i added in the design tool even tho they are the same size, so the text actually "fits" but it is off limits.